# Assert same object with sinon

Tags: sinon

Is there a way to assert that two objects are same or not?

I am trying to implement something like this

```
const initialObj = new MyObject(initialParam);

const resultObj = smthgChanged ? new MyObject(newParam) : initialObj;
```

Now I want to assert if smthgChanged is false `resultObj` is new object even all fields have same values otherwise it is same `initialObj`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to test for [Identity / strict equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity).

`sinon` doesn't provide a strict equality assertion because it is readily available elsewhere:

- [`.equal`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal) in `chai`
- [`.toBe`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobevalue) in `jest`
- [`.toBe`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toBe) in `jasmine`
- [`assert.strictEqual`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_strictequal_actual_expected_message) in Node's built-in `assert` module

Just use the strict equality assertion of your testing framework or assertion library.